# Embed an external website and insert javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, embed

I need to embed an external website and insert javascript, as you can see on http://shrturl.co/ (Not available at the moment) or http://harlemify.com/.
I don't want to use iframe or html object.
I am using nodejs and can't figure out how to do this.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: you cannot embed a website as a copy with any backend language, but you can use the api (if provided by the website), and you can build your own website in which you can add your custom CSS and javascript files,

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought it was possible using curl or something.

Comment: if you are going to use curl, then in return you will be getting the complete html response of the website, but the only problem is that the static files mentioned in the html code, must be there at your back end. If you want to do it like this, then create your own css and javascript files but with the same name as of the website your are scraping. This might work in your case